# Link two servers under the same namespace using DFS-N

Tags: dfs

I have set up two fileservers (Windows Server 2012 R2), namley; **filesrv01** & **filesrv02**. I have installed DFS-N and DFS-R on both the servers, in the goal of linking them both to a single namespace, namely; **filesrv**.

The idea is that the path should still prevail, should either one of the servers go offline. These servers are replicating data between them, but currently there is only one GPO on my domain controller that handles drive-maps to **filesrv01**. I would instead like to map the GPO to the name **filesrv**, which would make sure that the path could dynamically point to **filesrv02**, should the primary server fail.

How would I set this up using DFS namespace and folder structures?

Comment: It depends on how your shares are laid out on `filesrv01` and `filesrv02`. Can you give some examples of share structure/names/paths?

Comment: The servers look pretty much the same. Both servers have the same share mapped to the same drive-letter. For example; I have a drive-map called **Home(H:)**, which contains a shared folder named **Homes**. This folder contains user folders dynamically created by a GPO. This is then replicated from **filesrv01** to **filesrv02** to contain the same data. I would like to prioritize **filesrv01**, but if **filesrv02** is the only one that is reachable, it should instead be the server that is mapped, since it contains the same data.

Comment: Are these file servers also going to be the DFS roots? Are you looking to do a domain-based, or standalone namespace?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what the difference would imply. The point is to just access them, using the same namespace.

Comment: It seems you haven't done your reading, and aren't fully up to speed on the deployment options for DFS-N. The two types are explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770287(v=ws.11).aspx). I'd suggest  you go there, read and then update your question to include the relevant details.

Comment: I guess I should read up on the subject. Thank you for the link.